# Xming alternative for remotely connecting to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: ubuntu, remote

I'm currently using Xming (free version) to connect to my remote Ubuntu from my home Windows (I first connect to my remote Ubuntu using SSH and X11 forwarding to localhost).

The performance is, however, terrible: very, very slow, hangups etc.
My home connection is not very fast (1.5Mbs down / 160Kbps up), but I don't think this should be a real problem. Is there any other simple, free alternative? Perhaps something that will allow controlling color depth, rate of sync etc.?

Perhaps something that comes integrated in Ubuntu itself? I have root access to my Ubuntu so I can install new stuff if necessary (if needed - please tell me what to install using shell commands, please... I don't have GUI... :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [NoMachine NX or FreeNX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenx)?  It works well even on slow connections.  If you're not using a GUI on the remote Linux machine, why don't you just use SSH?

Comment: I am using a GUI on the remote machine (running, for example, gedit + R support). I use SSH most of the time, but sometimes I need GUI. Anyway, I will try the NX's you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: +1 wow, so far NoMachine seems awesome! the only thing I'm missing it to move to full screen mode, but I guess that's possible (I haven't found where all the options are hidden). BTW, I found these instruction useful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX#Installing%20the%20FreeNX%20server%20on%20Ubuntu%20Karmic%20%289.10%29%20%28Also%20works%20on%20Lucid%29

Comment: You should get the option to go full screen in the client connection wizard dialogue box.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I will second NoMachine. However, if you are trying to connect just so that you can transfer files, then try Binfer. Its a pretty good cross platform app to transfer large files. Sort of works like emails.

Comment: Binfer looks very useful, but in this case he could just use WinSCP for general use.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu enable remote VNC sessions from **System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop** and then just connect to your Ubuntu from your Windows with a VNC client of your choice. I'm not a regular Windows user so I don't know what's the best VNC client there.

Comment: I'm currently away from my Ubuntu. Do you know how can I achieve the same effect of **System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop** using a shell command?